# Uninitialized global variable in the map inside class metod

Tags: c++, constructor, global-variables

I have the following problem, I have a class that I want to be constructed from two different kinds of complex objects. There is a map inside a class method, that constructs from `extern` variables that I defined in the outer of the class. If I want to declare a class object inside the main function everything goes fine. But if I declare it outside the main, constructor of the class is called before the initialization of the extern objects from which I constructed the inner map in the class method. The error repeats itself on Clang and MSVC. If I use simple objects to construct the map (like `int` or `double`), everything works fine in both ways.

main.cpp

```
#include "TestClass.h"

TestClass test1 = TestClass(g_Spec1); // 1

int main()
{
    TestClass test2 = TestClass(g_Spec1); // 2
}
```

If you comment **1** everything works fine, however, as is, **2** didn't see extern variables.

TestClass.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

#include "Token.h"

extern const Spec_t g_Spec1;
extern const Spec_t g_Spec2;
extern const Spec_t g_Spec3;

extern const Name_t g_Name1;
extern const Name_t g_Name2;
extern const Name_t g_Name3;

class TestClass {
private:
    Name_t name;
    Spec_t spec;

    static const Name_t& foo(const Spec_t& j);

public:
    TestClass() = default;
    TestClass(const Spec_t& j);

    virtual ~TestClass() = default;
};
```

TestClass.cpp

```
#include "TestClass.h"

const Spec_t g_Spec1{ {Token::Type1, 2} };
const Spec_t g_Spec2{ {Token::Type1, 3} };
const Spec_t g_Spec3{ {Token::Type1, 4} };

const Name_t g_Name1{ "Name1" };
const Name_t g_Name2{ "Name2"};
const Name_t g_Name3{ "Name3" };

const Name_t& TestClass::foo(const Spec_t& spec_)
{
    static const std::map<Spec_t, Name_t > glmap1 =
    {
        {g_Spec1, g_Name1},
        {g_Spec2, g_Name2}
    };

    std::cout << "Foo: Map size must be 2, but it is " << glmap1.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "In FOO Name1 is " << g_Name1 << std::endl;

    auto constIterator = glmap1.find(spec_);
    if (constIterator == glmap1.cend())
    {
        std::cout << "Not found " << std::endl; // 3
        return g_Name3;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Found " << constIterator->second << std::endl; // 4
        return constIterator->second;
    }
}

TestClass::TestClass(const Spec_t& j)
{
    name = foo(j);
    spec = j;
    std::cout << "In CONSTRUCTOR name as global variable from map " << name << std::endl;
}
```

Another interesting thing is that **1** call **4**(Found) and **2** calls **3**(Not found) but the map is empty in both ways. Maybe it is because `g_Spec1` didn't initialize at this time?
And I didn't get why the map inside is debugger is empty, but have `size = 1`

Token.h

```
#pragma once
#include <cinttypes>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum class Token
{
    Type1,
    Type2
 };

struct TokenId
{
    Token tok;

    std::uint64_t val;

    bool operator==(const TokenId& p_Other) const noexcept
    {
        return (tok == p_Other.tok && val == p_Other.val);
    }

    bool operator<(const TokenId& p_Other) const noexcept
    {
        if (tok < p_Other.tok) return true;
        else if (tok == p_Other.tok)
        {
            return val < p_Other.val;
        }
        else return false;
    }
};

using Name_t = std::string;
using Spec_t = std::vector<TokenId>;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not entirely surprising. Initialization of global objects is partially ordered. Definitions from a single file are ordered by their appearance within that file, but there is no order across files.

You might see unexpected results in a debugger, because using uninitialized variables is undefined behavior.

This is just one of the reasons why global variables are best avoided. In your case, just put that variable inside `main()`.

Comment: Thank you. I get that it is similar to static initialization order fiasco, but why everything works fine when map is constructed not from `<Spec_t, Name_t>`, but from `<double, int>`? I can understand that optimization can put variables inside a map as when I use inline or constexpr, but in debug mode there is no optimization. And why initialization of global variables does not happen when I start execute main. Another one question is why if I left only initialization in main and delete static from map I get length error?

Comment: "Works fine" could be coincidence; I didn't see which values you used to initialize the `double` and `int`. Note that these globals will have values `0.0` and `0` respectively before being properly initialized;

Comment: As for removing `static`, you're then returning a reference to a local variable whose lifetime had ended. The map is destroyed before  you can use it.

Comment: Thank's `static` problems seems logically.

Comment: For `double` and `int` I used following code. TestClass.cpp https://pastebin.com/6MJVjNc4 TestClass.h https://pastebin.com/MYtVggzm and even if the map is not `static` it's works fine.